# Type erased reference wrapper that allows generic assignment, is that possible?

Tags: c++, type-erasure

Is it possible to create a class that stores a reference to variable of any type and allows generic assignment (with value of a distinct type)?

Imagine this interface:

```cpp
class any_ref {
public:
    ...

    // construct any_ref from reference
    template <class T>
    any_ref(T &ref);

    // does stored_ref = std::forward<U>(value) internally
    template <class U>
    void assign(U&& value);
};
```

I'm stuck and cannot figure out how to implement this. If we imagine that virtual template methods are possible, that would be easy:

```cpp
class any_ref {
public:
    ...

private:
    struct ref_holder {
        template <class U>
        virtual void assign(U&& value) = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct ref_holder_concrete : public ref_holder {
        template <class U>
        void assign(U&& value) override {
            stored_ref = std::forward<U>(value);
        }

        T &stored_ref;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<ref_holder> ref;
};
```

So I need some workaround of this impossibility. The problem is, there are two types involved in the operation of assignment. And for performing the operation we need to somehow retrieve one of that types from its type-erased storage.

Comment: No it's not. This is just `std::any` without the copying semantics.

Comment: @PasserBy can you please give more detail? Why exactly is it not possible?

>This is just std::any without the copying semantics.
What does this mean?

Comment: What you have here is literally just `std::any`, except you don't copy the object on copy. The `std::any` API demonstrates what's reasonably possible with type erasure of this kind. It's not possible because it's the limit of type erasure: you erased the type, but templates require you to know the type.